# How to open a file name that looks like a URL after require open-uri?

Tags: ruby, open-uri

How to open a file name that seems like a URL after require 'open-uri'

```
require 'open-uri'
open("http://google.com")
```

in folder

```
- http://google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [ruby-doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/), open-uri creates an alias to the original `open` called `open_uri_original_open`. You can use that method for enforcing opening local files.

But then, I'm not sure if you can really have filenames like `http://google.com` in your OS/filesystem.